# Pandas : converting a period from an 'object' type to a 'period' type, to be able to make calculations

Tags: python, pandas

I have just downloaded a basic file from NOAA (url : 'https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cag/time-series/global/globe/land_ocean/p12/12/1880-2020.csv') and there is this 'Period' which is currently an 'object' type, displaying stg like a YYYYMM value :

```
import pandas as pd
test=pd.read_csv('https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cag/time-series/global/globe/land_ocean/p12/12/1880-2020.csv', parse_dates=['Year'], infer_datetime_format=True, skiprows=4)
test.columns=['Period','Discr']
test.head()

Period  Discr
0   188001  -0.06
1   188002  -0.14
2   188003  -0.09
3   188004  -0.05
4   188005  -0.09

test.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1683 entries, 0 to 1682
```

Data columns (total 2 columns):

```
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   Period  1683 non-null   object 
 1   Discr   1683 non-null   float64
dtypes: float64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 26.4+ KB
```

I tried to use `dt.to_period(freq='M'), pd.PeriodIndex ...` but couldn't solve my issue...

Hence my need for help. Thanks in advance

Comment: use `dt['Year'].dt.to_period(freq='m')`

Comment: Thks @jezrael for this but I can't figure out how to use this : 'dt' means I have to import datetime module at first I guess, which I did. But then if I type `test['Period'] = test['Period'].dt.to_Period(freq='M')`, (as test is the data frame name, and Period the column name), I nevertheless still have an error `AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values`... :-/

Comment: So first use `df['Period'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Period'])`

Comment: I did so at first, and it eventually worked out properly, until it appeared that the default calendar start at 1970 - 01 - 01 :-/ whereas my datas start at 1880 - 01 - 01. Here as well I figured out a way to deal with this. This for your precious help !!

Comment: OK, I got it. Answer was added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use custom function, edited function from [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#representing-out-of-bounds-spans):

```
df['Period']=df['Period'].apply(lambda x: pd.Period(year=x // 100, month=x % 100, freq='M'))
print (df)
    Period  Discr
0  1880-01  -0.06
1  1880-02  -0.14
2  1880-03  -0.09
3  1880-04  -0.05
4  1880-05  -0.09
```